# slick2.0: how to make a Table object?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

Hi I just update and run the the simple slick Table and want to inquire it.

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery

class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Double)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def * = (name, price)
}
val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees];
```

The error is:

```
[error] C:\testprojects\slickplay\app\model\Coffee.scala:11: expected class or o bject definition
[error] val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees];
```

The TableQuery[Coffees] do not return objects???how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a val outside of a class or object definition.

Try

```
object DatabaseContext {
  val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put all things in side trait:

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

trait DomainComponent{

   class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Double)](tag, "COFFEES") {
     def name = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
     def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
     def * = (name, price)
    }
  val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

object coffees extends TableQuery(new Coffees(_))

Comment: Could you expand this a bit?

Comment: my apologies, it doesnt seeem like you can. Theres a few good examples (specifically play) on how to struct an app here: https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/tree/master/samples